# Packages in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

Is it possible to create packages of related classes and have the same `protected` and `private` fields which are visible only to classes from within the same package?

Basically, the same type of packages as what Java has.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right now, there is no concept of package.

However, PHP 5.3 is going to introduce [namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php). I'm not sure about how that will affect visibility between classes.

Answer (score 4):

Nope.  PHP has no package or friend-class support.

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested to read http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2012/03/packages-the-way-forward-for-php

Short answer - http://getcomposer.org/

Answer (score 2):

Here are two approaches I've stumbled upon pondering the same issue:

[Simulating Packages in PHP](http://www.codediesel.com/php/simulating-packages-in-php/)

[PHP Package Management and Autoloading](http://jacwright.com/40/php-package-management-and-autoloading/)

And it looks like there are some more import analogs in the [PHP require_once() docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php). Hope it helps someone going forward.